# Shapes layer seems to move with scrolling

Tags: html, kineticjs

I have applied the following tutorial in a JavaScript script:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-interactive-building-map/

It works like a charm in most cases. Whenever I scroll the entire website, everything goes well, hovering over the shapes works perfect.

But whenever I make a div inside the website scrollable with the shape in it, the visible shapes do stay in place (with visible shapes I mean what you're actually seeing), together with the picture, but whenever I hover, I have to hover lower whenever I scroll down, as can be seen on:

http://i45.tinypic.com/28cn7ur.png
(notice the position of the scrollbar and the position of my mouse relative to the blue shape above it)

The div in the center is positioned relative, and within this div I have a canvas-wrapper div (also position relative) and therein the canvas itself.

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using kinetic version 3.8.2, upgrading to version 3.10.4 fixed the problem.